# Are Generation 1 Pokémon still able to hatch from eggs if they have a Generation 2 preevolution?

Tags: pokemon-go

Within a Pokémon evolution family, only the first Pokémon is available from an egg.  For example, in the Bulbasaur family - Bulbasaur, Ivysaur, and Venusaur - only Bulbasaur can be hatched from an egg.

But now as generation 2 Pokémon have been introduced, some of those evolve into the generation 1 Pokémon, which are also available from eggs.  For instance, Cleffa evolves into Clefairy. Clefairy was able to be hatched before the update, but I don't know now as Clefairy is generation 1 whilst Cleffa is generation 2.

So are those generation 1 species still able to hatch from eggs?

Answer (score 16):

**Update:** SilphRoad did [the research](https://thesilphroad.com/science/hatching-evolved-pokemon-and-regionals) and the answer is NO.

**Original answer:** I have not hatched any of the adults personally, but yes, adult versions of the Pokémon were reported to be hatched from eggs obtained after the baby Pokémon have been introduced (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5i4ial/has_anyone_hatched_a_magmar_jynx_and_electabuzz/db5a6ms/), or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5i4ial/has_anyone_hatched_a_magmar_jynx_and_electabuzz/db5j3n8/)). So as long as we trust the report authors, the answer is yes.